# Possibility of an output for this integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Any clues as to whether an output exists for this expression where `t and f` are positive real numbers that can be treated as constants

```
Integrate[k*(-(1/(-1 + t*E^k^2)) + 
          1/(-1 + t*f*E^k^2))*(1/Sqrt[k^2 - el]),
          {k, e1, Infinity}]
```

I have set the lower limit to `e1` (real positive integer) to eliminate complex numbers as output

Comment: What assumptions can be made about the constants?

Comment: The constants are positive real numbers

Comment: Is `el` also a positive real number?  In any case, the integral will be a complex number.  Is that what you expect?

Comment: e1 is positive real. Suppose I restrict the lower limit to e1 (instead of zero), will that help to eliminate complex numbers?

Comment: Even with the change of variable ` k^2 ->x`, the simplified integral `Integrate[1/(-1 + E^x)/Sqrt[x - el], {x, el, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> el > 0]` does not  produce a result.  On the other hand, `NIntegrate[1/((-1 + E^x) Sqrt[-1 + x]), {x, 1, Infinity}]` works fine.